# Angular Pipes: Apply date format pipe and join on array

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to apply a pipe to each element of an array and join the result afterwards? (just in the html template)

Something like this would be great:

```
...
<span>{{ someDateArray  | date| join:', ' }}</span>
...
```

Comment: I'd really consider doing this in the component, not in the template. BTW - you can use pipes (like the date pipe) inside your component as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of someDataArray; let isLast=last">
   {{ item | date }}{{ isLast ? '' : ', ' }}
</span>
```